# Create a Group using a CSV of existing contacts with an ID

Tags: search, groups, mailing

Sorry for the potentially elementary question here, bur I have seen this done by a former coworker. I can't for the life of me remember how to use a CSV or comma delimited string of CiviCRM IDs to create a new mailing group through the CiviCRM user interface. I have a list of existing contacts from our database that has been filtered inside Excel and now I need to create a new group off the remaining contact IDs.

Can anyone remind me how to take the CSV list to create the search and then generate the new group? Or do I have to run the list through the "Import Contacts" process and add them to a group that way?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the import contacts wizard with a file of the contact IDs that you want to add to a group - in the field mapping screen, just map to contact ID, and in the import verification screen you have the option of adding contacts to a new or existing group.

Hope this helps!
Tamar

Comment: That's what I was thinking, just wasn't sure if I was going to be making a bunch of dupes if I use "Update" or nothing if I choose "skip" on the dedupe step. 

Thanks Tamar.

Comment: Glad I could help! To clarify, the mapping is set to match to contact ID, so since you generated the list from existing contacts and regardless of what dedupe option you select, using "update" carries no risk of creating dupes.